# Why casting void pointer to char pointer doesn't work in this situation

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I've got void pointer which I want to do pointer arithmetic on it.
to do so, I want to cast it to a char pointer.

```
( char * ) buf += current_size;
```

However when I do so, I get the following error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

I tried also adding parenthesis on the the whole left side, with no success.
Why do I get this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the warning by writing the assignment operator out:

```
buf = (char *)buf + current_size;
```

Part of the reason you get the warning is that `sizeof(void)` is undefined and you cannot do arithmetic on `void *`.  Beware: GCC has an extension whereby it treats the code as if `sizeof(void) == 1`, but that is not in the C standard.

The cast on the LHS of the assignment has no effect on the assignment.

Comment: Should that be *"...you cannot do arithmetic on `void`"*? If it were a pointer with a type, then you could do math on it.

Comment: @jww: you can't do arithmetic on `void` either.

Answer (score 5):

> Why do I get this

Simply because the language rules state that a cast does not produce an lvalue **even if the operand is one**.

> [ISO/IEC 9899:201x - n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/post-London-2011.htm)
>
> In a footnote, page 91
>
> A cast does not yield an lvalue.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's invalid, you can't do this. If you want to achieve this, either

declare buf as a char pointer;
or use a temporary variable:

```
char *tmp = buf; // note you don't need the casting, void * works with everything
tmp += current_size;
buf = tmp;
```

Edit: as others also suggested, you can even remove that ugly tmp:

```
buf = (char *)buf + current_size;
```